# how to open another browser instance or tab from within a page viewer web part

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0, html

I made a simple graphical object in Microsoft Excel 2007; I saved it as as web page and uploaded it to a document library. Thereafter, I used a page viewer web part to show my page. However, whenever I click on one of the hyperlinks the web page has, it opens inside the web part frame and not in another browser instance/tab. How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an Excel issue than SharePoint.  However, when you create links in Excel, there is no way to specify the target of a URL.  (For instance, you would need _blank to create a new window).  When you export from Excel, the target is set to _parent.  Only way to achieve this would be to edit the HTML files themselves to replace _parent with _blank on the targets of the links.

Comment: It seems that excel maintains a list of resources in an xml file, so it wasn't possible to set the target to _blank. My aim is just to have an a graphic in a web page where a portion of it links to another html page inside the same sharepoint site. The graphic is not simple enough and it would be painful to do it writing html, that's why I used Excel in this case.

Comment: update: I hadn't located the right .htm file to make the appropriate changes. It now works as you said.